# Typescript 2.0 + VS 2015 @types not working

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript, typescript2.0

iam using:

```
Visual Studio 2015 with NodeJs Tools 1.2
TypeScript 2.0 (updated from 1.8)
```

When i compile typescript with `tsc` everything works.

But in Visual Studio modules like express are not found.

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "rootDir": "src/",
    "outDir": "target/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "target"
  ]
}
```

i installed express typing as

```
"@types/express": "^4.0.33",
```

and iam using it like

```
import * as express from 'express';
```

but module wasnt found. ONLY IN VISUAL STUDIO

Answer (score 0):

ok well,
i needed to install the new typescript tools for visual studio from
[microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=48593)